# Pandas not seeing data as datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Panda is not picking up date time (ie, I need to keep minutes and seconds), nor can I convert it.

```
    import pandas as pd

    rides = pd.read_parquet('../data/raw/rides_2022-01.parquet')

    rides.head(20)

    rides = rides[['pickup_datetime', 'PULocationID']]

    rides.rename(columns={
        'tpep_pickup_datetime': 'pickup_datetime',
        'PULocationID': 'pickup_location_id',
    }, inplace=True)

     rides.to_datetime(rides['pickup_datetime'])  <-- errors here AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

    rides['pickup_datetime'].describe(include='all')

        count                          2463879
        mean     2022-01-17 01:58:40.393673472
        min                2022-01-01 00:00:08
        25%                2022-01-09 15:37:56
        50%                2022-01-17 12:11:54
        75%                2022-01-24 13:49:37
        max                2022-01-31 23:59:58
        Name: pickup_datetime, dtype: object
```

Comment: rides['pickup_datetime'] = pd.to_datatime(rides['pickup_datetime'])

Comment: However, it seems that your data contains data that cannot be converted to datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax

```
rides["pickup_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(rides["pickup_datetime"])
rides.dtypes
```

Output:

```
pickup_datetime    datetime64[ns]
...
```